Past Tense Story Telling
I'm a part-time hobby-writer, an average book reader....
The question I have for you is... I noticed that most writers favour the 'Past Tense' style in their writing and it leaves an open question in my head: what's the rule of usage of 'have'?
For example, usually we say "He has been a great guy". But if a person tells it from the perspective of the past, which requires Sequence of tenses, then would it be logically converted to "He had been a great guy"?
P.S. Since not a lot understood the question, I'll make it more narrow and straight. If I tell the story in the past tense, will all Present Perfect turn into Past Perfect? And what will happen If I already had Past Perfect in my storyline and I want to use it again? How do I do that correct?!

In what context would 'we' say "I have been a great guy"? (NB Etc. needs neither 'and' before it nor full stops between the letters.)

In most cases the "sequence of tenses" backshift occurs in the subordinate clause of reported speech. For example: "He said that he had been a great guy." Similarly, it is conceivable in a first-person narrative to have "He said that I had been a great guy". Is this the context you are asking about?

There are many questions addressing 'sequence of tenses' (including use of past simple, past continuous when backshifting might be expected by an inexperienced user) and backshifting itself. But your question is unclear; << We say "He has been a great guy" >> (I've edited to make it sound less cheesy). If you mean this as direct speech,  it obviously becomes << We said  "He has been a great guy" >> if the speech was in the past, or << We say  "He had been a great guy" >> if you add sequencing context such as "before his untimely death". But by 'we say' do you mean 'one would normally write'?

"She had never been much of a fan of tanning beds, but she looked especially pale about now. PERFECT. Why? Because how she looked is preceded by the other idea. That is one of the main ways the past perfect is used, preceding something else: how she looked.

It is usual to write fiction in the past tense. The past perfect is used to refer to events that happened before the time in which the story takes place. For instance, a character who is an adult in the story 'had been brought up by his grandparents, because his parents had been killed in an accident'.
Your example of someone who 'had never been a fan of tanning beds' is indeed the past perfect.

Kate you're ultimately the coolest person around the place! Thank you kindly ;)

Would you like to accept my answer, then?
